# elastic search rails Validate Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

i am going to use `https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails` in my rails app for searching. I have successfully installed `DEB file` on ubuntu by running this

```
sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-1.4.2.deb
```

i am following this tutorial

`http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch/`

there they say

```
Open this url: http://localhost:9200 and you’ll see ElasticSearch respond like so:
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Anvil",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.2.1",
    "build_hash" : "6c95b759f9e7ef0f8e17f77d850da43ce8a4b364",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-06-03T15:02:52Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.8"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

but when i go to localhost:9200 it will give me `This webpage is not available`

here is my elasticsearch.yml

```
config = {
  host: "http://localhost:9200/",
  transport_options: {
    request: { timeout: 5 }
  },
}

if File.exists?("config/elasticsearch.yml")
  config.merge!(YAML.load_file("config/elasticsearch.yml").symbolize_keys)
end

Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(config)
```

and when i search it will give me this and on view page it shows me nothing

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hMQQxSLAckDdmLAIMn8nTPv2BOe8v0l1dtMsfi9TEW4=", "q"=>"qwerty", "commit"=>"Go"}
  Admin Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins"  WHERE "admins"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
***********************************************************
#<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Response:0x007f0114b48310 @klass=[PROXY] Feed(id: integer, title: string, json_data: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, image: string, url: string, user_name: string, user_image: string, slug: string, custom_thumbnail_file_name: string, custom_thumbnail_content_type: string, custom_thumbnail_file_size: integer, custom_thumbnail_updated_at: datetime, custom_user_image_file_name: string, custom_user_image_content_type: string, custom_user_image_file_size: integer, custom_user_image_updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, front_page_title: string, primary_category: string, status: string, primary_category_title: string, add_description: text, add_short_description: text, is_premium: boolean, is_course: boolean, price: float, supply: text, process: text, body_text: text, link: text, direct_link: text, procedure: text, status_message: string, short_url: string, course_status: string, pinterest_image_file_name: string, pinterest_image_content_type: string, pinterest_image_file_size: integer, pinterest_image_updated_at: datetime, pinterest_image_url: string), @search=#<Elasticsearch::Model::Searching::SearchRequest:0x007f0114b49ad0 @klass=[PROXY] Feed(id: integer, title: string, json_data: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, image: string, url: string, user_name: string, user_image: string, slug: string, custom_thumbnail_file_name: string, custom_thumbnail_content_type: string, custom_thumbnail_file_size: integer, custom_thumbnail_updated_at: datetime, custom_user_image_file_name: string, custom_user_image_content_type: string, custom_user_image_file_size: integer, custom_user_image_updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, front_page_title: string, primary_category: string, status: string, primary_category_title: string, add_description: text, add_short_description: text, is_premium: boolean, is_course: boolean, price: float, supply: text, process: text, body_text: text, link: text, direct_link: text, procedure: text, status_message: string, short_url: string, course_status: string, pinterest_image_file_name: string, pinterest_image_content_type: string, pinterest_image_file_size: integer, pinterest_image_updated_at: datetime, pinterest_image_url: string), @options={}, @definition={:index=>"feeds", :type=>"feed", :q=>"qwerty"}>>
```

Any help will be appreciable thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see the guide about the setup of the debian package http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html#_debian_ubuntu

by default Elasticsearch does not start, when installed as a package, you need to start it manually by running

`/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start`

If you want to start Elasticsearch on startup add this

`sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10`

Comment: thanks for the reply... {
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Mother Night",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.4.2",
    "build_hash" : "927caff6f05403e936c20bf4529f144f0c89fd8c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-12-16T14:11:12Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
Now when i search it gives me [404] {"error":"IndexMissingException[[feeds] missing]","status":404}